# Почему возникает ошибка Cannot read property objectWithSizes of null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, объекты, null

Доброго времени суток друзья, на странице возникает ошибка: Cannot read property objectWithSizes of null. Она возникает только на определенной странице, на всех остальных работает номрально. В чем может быть проблема?

```js
type ComponentState = {
  objectWithSizes?: {
    height?: number,
    offset?: number,
    id?: string
  };
};

export function withScrollToFirstError(Component: t.form.Component): React.ComponentType {
  class ScrollToFirstErrorHOC extends PureComponent<OuterProps & PropsFromState, ComponentState> {
    componentDidUpdate() {
      const { arrayOfSizes, firstFieldId, currentFieldId, firstError } = this.props;
      this.pushToArray(currentFieldId, firstFieldId, arrayOfSizes);
    }

    pushToArray = (currentFieldId: string, firstFieldId: string, arrayOfSizes: Array<any>) => {
      if (currentFieldId === firstFieldId) {
        arrayOfSizes.splice(0, arrayOfSizes.length);
      }
      arrayOfSizes.push(this.state.objectWithSizes);
    };

    public render() {
      return (
        <View
          onLayout={({ nativeEvent: { layout } }) => {
            this.setState({
              objectWithSizes: {
                height: layout.height,
                offset: layout.y,
                id: this.props.currentFieldId,
              },
            });
          }}
        >
          <Component {...this.props} />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: В заголовке страницы скрипт подключен?

Comment: с кодом все нормально. Случайно заметил, что ошибка возникает только в том случае, если включен debugger. Но, не могу понять из за чего, и как дебаггер может влиять на стэйт приложение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Контекст в методе `pushToArray()` указывает не на компонент

- или опишите метод не присваивая его к свойству

```
pushToArray(currentFieldId: string, firstFieldId: string, arrayOfSizes: Array<any>) {
    ....
};
```

- или забиндите контекст при вызове в конструкторе

```
this.pushToArray.call(this, currentFieldId, firstFieldId, arrayOfSizes)
```

Comment: `pushToArray(currentFieldId: string, firstFieldId: string, arrayOfSizes: Array<any>) => {` - это синтаксическая ошибка

Comment: `this.pushToArray.bind(this)(currentFieldId, firstFieldId, arrayOfSizes)` зачем так, если для вызова можно использовать `call`, который сразу вызывает функцию, вместо создания обертки

Comment: @Grundy Сэнкс, стрелочную функцию поправил, а про call и вовсе забыл 100 лет его не юзал